# Bug in Word 2007 ConditionalStyle

Tags: vba, word-2007

I'm using the Word 2007 object model to manipulate tables.  Whenever I read the `Shading` or `Borders` properties of a `ConditionalStyle` object for a table's style (using VBA or C#), it resets the table's applied conditional styles to Header Row, Banded Rows, and First Column, and it clears all table-level formatting (borders and shading).

This happens whether I access `ConditionalStyle` through the table's `Style` property or through the document's `Style` collection.

To reproduce the problem, make a Word 2007 document that has a table with some formatting (borders or shading) applied, select any part of the table, and run the following code in VBA's Immediate Window:

```
print Selection.Tables(1).Style.Table.Condition(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor
```

The table will be reset as described above.

Can other people reproduce this issue in their environment? (I reproduced it in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2003 using Word 2007 SP1 and SP2)

Can anyone guess why this is happening?

Can anyone find a workaround to read the Shading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this by selecting a part of the document that is outside the table before checking the `ConditionalStyle`; the bug only occurs when the selection is within the table.

I still don't know why it's happening, though.